# Werkzeug gives ssl.SSLEOFError when accepting requests using flask-restful

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

Functionality isn't affected by this issue, but it is quite annoying to see the console spam from it. This kind of error has been asked about in many stack overflow questions, but none seem to quite match up with this variation of the error.

These are the components of my setup I believe might influence this issue:

```
import ssl
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, request
from flask_cors import CORS

...

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})
api = Api(app, default_mediatype='application/json')

api.add_resource(SystemProperties, '/assets/system/properties/<property>')

...

context = ('/etc/ssl/server_crt.pem', '/etc/ssl/server_key.pem')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, port=18080, debug=False, ssl_context=context)
```

I've tried updating all packages including openssl, pyopenssl. I've installed  ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 urllib3.

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 296, in execute
    write(b"")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 275, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 594, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 869, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 594, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1949)
```

Comment: Wanted to give an update: I am now using Gunicorn to serve the API and this issue is no longer present. It seems like it has something to do with the suppress_ragged_eofs option. Nonetheless, it would still be interesting to get some insight on the root of the issue.

Comment: I guess you have not found yet a solution using flask+werkzeug. I have noticed that this only happen when response is empty, or an option petition is made.